# What is the correct error model for clock uncertainty?

Tags: probability, statistics

If a clock has 20ppm accuracy, after 1 million seconds the error in predicted time is $\pm{}20$ seconds right? If the time measurements are independent, then after N million seconds uncertainty on total time would be $\pm{}20\sqrt{N}$. But this seems to give unreasonable predictions of how good clocks should be, basically that they seem to get more accurate the longer they run.

Usually I see total time drift being represented simply by $\pm{}20N$ after N million seconds. What is the distribution that leads to this type of error propagation? Is it a non-symmetric distribution? One involving correlation? Is it possible to characterize these parameters for a real clock to get more accurate time?

Any references that talk about clocks regarding error propagation and time drift would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The model of clock uncertainty is *not* that it is sometimes too fast, sometimes too slow.  Instead it is that it has a fixed deviation from "true" rate (within the specified range), and thus as time goes on the absolute difference between "true" time and the shown time increases, on average.

Answer (score 0):

Assume the simplest possible model: that the length of each tick is an independent random sample from a Gaussian distribution.

Then after $N$ ticks, the expected difference between the actual and ideal readings of the clock is $\left|\text{actual mean} - \text{ideal tick length}\right| N + (\text{standard deviation}) \sqrt{2N/\pi}$. (I'm not sure I have the constant factors right, but it doesn't affect the conclusion.)

This will have $O(\sqrt N)$ growth only if the mean of the distribution is precisely equal to the correct tick length. Otherwise the $O(N)$ term will eventually dominate.